# MBstring not loading, phpMyAdmin fatal error etc etc on WINDOWS 7 PRO local server

Tags: php, mbstring

Trying to install a local server for testing on a WINDOWS SEVEN PRO (Windows 7 pro). This is not the first time I installed local servers, but I never worked with phpMyAdmin so that aspect is new for me.

Installed Apache 2.4.10 64 bit and and PHP 5.6.3 (x64) on my PC as local server for testing a forum set-up. Installed Apache and configured: works ok with my websites. Installed PHP, localhost:info.php gives the entire php info sheet so PHP works also.

However, the mbstring module does not show up in the php info sheet.

Copied phpMyAdmin to the htdocs folder of Apache. Installing gives the error message

```
"fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177"; also showing that the mbstring is not functional
```

I spent over a day browsing through internet, finding similar threads but none with an answer that works for me.

php.ini
I started with uncommenting the extension=php_mbstring.dll, then I added an absolute directory path and now the php.ini is as follows

Directory path

```
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext\"
```

The following lines are uncommented

```
extension=php_gd2.dll 
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

The php.ini file originally was in the php directory. I then moved it to the apache root directory (c:\apache24\htdocs and now the php.ini file is in three identical copies (everytime carefully copied and refreshed) in the c:\windows folder, the C:\php folder and the c:\apache24\htdocs folder.

The php_mbstring.dll file (1.4 mb in size) is in the php\ext folder and the php.ini file has an absolute path to that directory.

both apache and PHP are under their own folders on c: level, so short paths and no spaces in paths like with the "program folder"

Apache monitor has been stopped and started, restarted and the whole PC switched off and restarted.

I even downloaded a one-month newer version of PHP and still no dice.

Summarizing: the mbstring is uncommented and present but not showing up on the php info-sheet and phpMyAdmin also has problems locating it?

Our nrw forum will be multiple language and I have to make this work somehow.
Again, we are talking W7 with individually installed Apache, php, and phpMyAdmin